# Suddenly not able to send email by amazon SES - unable to connect smtp host

Tags: java, email, amazon-ec2, smtp, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES from almost 4 months with same code, same port number(25) everything same. But from past 1 week I am not able to send email - while sending this error comes:

The email was not sent.
Error message: Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, port: 25

I am using the same code for sending email that amazon suggests to use from link (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html)

We are working on a website project and using it inside it. Its not a problem with me alone, my team members of 4 working under same internet gateway, all of them are not able to send email from 1 week from their **localhost**.

But when we deploy the same code on Amazon ec2, top-level domain say **sample.com** then it starts working but when we deploy the same code under a sub-domain say **beta.sample.com** then again same error starts coming.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 4):

## Passing outgoing SMTP (25) port connections bloc

Try sending your email via email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587.

Outgoing connections to SMTP (25) port may be blocked by a firewall to stop outgoing spam.

Can you telnet any of the two ports? Do you get SMTP greeting messages?

```
telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 25
telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 587
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent

> Many Internet service providers and enterprise or institutional networks restrict the ability to connect to remote MTAs on port 25. The accessibility of a Mail Submission Agent on port 587[1] enables nomadic users to continue to send mail via their preferred submission servers even from within others' network

Comment: I am not able to connect via telnet also. But i don't think so there is a problem from my end. If it is so, then could you explain me the reason, why the same website hosted on a sub-domain in same server is experiencing the same problem?

Comment: And yes connection via 587 is successful, but I would like to know the reason why Port 25 and 495 is failing on both localhost and sub-domain hosted in same ec2 server but works fine on primary domain.

Comment: On Linux/BSD you may use programs like `tcptraceroute` to locate the  firewall responsible for blocking connections.